# Copy VMWare Instances that are in Active Directry

Tags: windows, vmware-server, active-directory

Is there any way to be able to automate the cloning of Windows XP VMWare Machines that are part of an Active Directory domain?
The machines are part of a testing infrastructure. They should have the identical software installed and they should also be able to run simultaneously on the same network + domain.
If I just copy the "master" image and change the VM's MAC, I'll probably still have problems with AD.
Using a sysprep'ed image would lead to problems with the automation, since I'd have to get on the domain again.
This might be a problem without a solution, but maybe I'm just missing something.

Thanks,
Marc

p.s. using the free vmware server at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use sysprep to have it join the domain after reboot  (start [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302577) for references) however if this is something you want to do on a regular basis you're far better off investing some time in setting up [Remote Installation Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786442(WS.10).aspx).  If at all possible, windows deployment services from 2008 (which is a successor to RIS) is event easier to set up and get running.

The relevent sysprep section is below:

```
[Identification]
;Specify whether to join a domain or workgroup
; JoinWorkgroup=MyWorkGroup
JoinDomain=MyDomain
;Specify the OU which will contain the computer account.
;This must already exist.
MachineObjectOU="OU=WinXP, DC=MyDomain, DC=com"
;Specify account information which will be
;used to join the computer to the domain
DomainAdmin=MyDomain\Administrator
DomainAdminPassword=MyPassword
EncryptedDomainAdminPassword=No
```

Alternatively you could do this via a script after sysprep completes

Comment: sadly, the developer team I work for is not responsible for the domain -> no domain admin account :(  
As I said, there might not be a real solution to that problem.

But since your info might be pretty valueable, I'll mark it as correct :)